# Find algebraic function to describe number of people "x"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a group of x people, Joe ordered 5 pizza pies, each of which was cut into 12 slices. Each person was originally supposed to have an equal number of slices. However, four people did not want any pizza, so when the pizza was distributed among the remaining people, each of them received four more slices. Which of the following equations could be used to find x?

A. $ x^2-4x-60=0$

B. $ x^2-4x+60=0$

C. $ x^2+4x-60=0$

D. $ x^2+4x+60=0$

E. $ x^2-16x-240=0$

I have no idea. Could I get any hints?

Comment: I edited the problem to give the given answer choices of the question.

Comment: How many slices are there altogether? Say $N$. Then what's the relation between $\frac{N}{x}$ and $\frac{N}{x-4}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. of slices with each person on equal distribution = $\frac{60}{x}$

No. of slices with each person after four persons refuse = $\frac{60}{x-4}$

The difference is $4$.
Hence$$\frac{60}{x-4}-\frac{60}{x}=4$$

Comment: Shouldn't $60/(x-4) =4$? $60/(x-4)$ is the additional number of slices that each person gets, which is equal to 4.

Comment: No $\frac{60}{x-4}$ is the *absolute* number of slices each person gets whereas 4 is the number of *additional* slices

Answer (score 2):

There are $5\times12=60$ slices, so at the beginning each one should receive $a=\frac{60}{x}$ slices.

When $4$ give their slices to the others, each of the remaining has $4$ more slices, so
$$\frac{60}{x-4}=a+4$$

Hence
$$\frac{60}{x-4}=\frac{60}x+4$$

Now multiply each term by $x(x-4)$, to get

$$60x=60(x-4)+4x(x-4)$$
$$60x=60x-240+4x^2-16x$$

$$4x^2-16x-240=0$$

Or, dividing by $4$,

$$x^2-4x-60=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach: Let $y$ be the number of slices each person originally gets. So, $y=\frac{5\times12}{x}=\frac{60}{x}$

If 4 people don't have pizza then 60 slices were distributed among $(x-4)$ people. So each got $\frac{60}{(x-4)}$ slices. Again, it is said that each got 4 slices more than they originally were supposed to get.

So $\frac{60}{(x-4)}=(y+4)$

i.e. $\frac{60}{(x-4)}=(\frac{60}{x}+4)$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another route through.

Let the initial allocation per person be $N$ slices so that $Nx=60$, then the revised allocation tells us that $$Nx=(N+4)(x-4)=Nx-4N+4x-16$$ whence $x-N-4=0$ (or $x=N+4$) which we can multiply through by $x$ to obtain $$x^2-Nx-4x=x^2-4x-60=0$$

---

Alternatively substitute $N=x-4$ directly.

Using a general number $a\neq 0$ instead of $4$ we get that $$Nx=(N+a)(x-a) \implies x=N+a$$ and the two factorisations simply have the factors interchanged. In this case we are looking at two factors of $60$ which differ by $4$